# How to pass a command to dev console while automating selenium testcase

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am writing an automation test case wherein i need to pass a specific command on chrome dev console to activate a plugin required for my test case.
I am using selenium framework for my tests.

This is the flow:

1. Open the homepage
2. Run the command on dev console
3. Continue with rest of the test steps

top.startTour("123", 0) is the command

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please review your post and add some code AND a QUESTION (I don't see any)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to execute some Javascript?

If that is the case you can do so by using the `JavascriptExecutor` in you test.
In your case your code should look something like this

```
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) webdriver;
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("top.startTour('123', 0)");
```

Here is a nice [article](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html) on how to use the `JavascriptExecutor` in more detail.

Comment: Do you know how it can be done in testcafe?.. looks like the tests are in testcafe and i need to have this command in testcafe framework?